# Remove blank line in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How can I remove lines that only contain spaces when using Eclipse Find/Replace prompt.  I checked the "Regular Expression" check box, and tried the following, neither of which worked.

```
^[:space:]*$
```

and

```
^\s*$
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Find: `^\s*\n`

Replace with: (empty)

Comment: make sure you check the regular expressions option, otherwise it won't work http://mcuoneclipse.com/2012/08/28/removing-blank-lines-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 7):

sry this might be an different answer but you can set the number of blank lines you wish to have after fields, methods and blocks in the formatting dialog of the eclipse preferences. then you can hit ctrl-shift-f to automatically format your code depending on your custom definitions.

have fun!

Comment: The file I am attempting to replace the blank lines from is not a source code file.

Comment: you might try to add the desired filetype to your eclipse file associations under "Preferences/General/Editors/File Associations" and link it with a specific editor, which is capable of handling your source files.

Answer (score 4):

1. for the find/replace operation, "\n\r\s" regex will work on windows, for unix based system, "\n\s" can be used
2. as already suggested, you can format your code by Ctl+Shift+F
3. for manual work, locate a blank line and press Ctl+D (Cmd+D on Mac) <- gives u satisfaction of killing the line with your own bare hands :)

cheer!

Answer (score 4):

I was suprised that for XML files edited with Eclipse there is a good solution:

- Select the checkbox value named 'Clear all blank lines' in Formatting panel
  Window->Preferences->XML->XML Files-> Editor
- Save and use the "Ctrl+Shift+F' shortcut

The blank lines will dissappear!

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me for years:

Replace this: `[\t ]+$`

With nothing

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to lamamac.
In genereal, when you want to do search replace with regular expressions in eclipse the $ sign doesn't work as it should.
Use '`\s*\n`' instead of '`$`'

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, regular expression and replacement is the solution, but such response would have been saving some minutes to me:

1. click on ctrl+f
2. use this replacement:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Use this below pattern as shown below in any IDE Editor**

> `^\s*\n`

[image]