# Remove double spacing in eclipse

Tags: java, apache-flex, flash-builder

I imported my project into eclipse and it became double spaced. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Tried:**

```
Find: [\t ]+$ 
Replace With: Nothing //error: incompatible line delimiter

Find: \s*\n 
Replace With: Nothing //error: incompatible line delimiter

Find:  ^\s*\r?\n
Replace With: /R //error: incompatible line delimiter

Find:  ^\s*\r?\n
Replace With: nothing //string not found

Find:  (.)\r\n(.)
Replace With: nothing //string not found

File > Convert Line Delimiters to > Windows //no changes

Source > Apply Formatting //grayed out

CTRL + Shift + F //doesn't remove double spaces
```

Comment: Why not using the *Source > Format* function on the whole project?

Comment: @LaurentG , Source > Apply formatting is grayed out, and I believe that is what ctrl+shift+f calls.

Comment: I wonder why it became double spaced in the first place. Eclipse can handle CR+LF as line delimiter without problem. 1. Make sure that the project wasn't broken to begin with. 2. What's the default line delimiter for the project? It's in the Project Properties.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove empty lines in eclipse code editior by find/replace (Ctrl+F)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619851/remove-empty-lines-in-eclipse-code-editior-by-find-replace-ctrlf)

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18992188/34088

Comment: I tried all of the answers in the possible duplicate link, it was posted below in an answer already. And line delimiter is 'inherited from container'. And no, there are no problems with the project besides the double spacing. - @AaronDigulla

Comment: When you open the files outside of Eclipse, do they already have two line delimiters? What happens when you set the line delimiter to a fixed value?

Comment: How did you import the project into Eclipse?

Comment: I fixed it and answered my own question, thanks for trying to help. I will choose my question in 2 days when it allows me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `project properties` I went to the `flexFormatter` and changed the option `keep this many blank lines` to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried (with regex check on of course):

Find: ^\s*\r?\n

Replace with: \R

This finds one or double lines and replaces it with one line.

**EDIT:**

There is a related post, maybe one of the answers is the right one for you: [Remove empty lines in eclipse code editor by find/replace (Ctrl+F)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619851/remove-empty-lines-in-eclipse-code-editior-by-find-replace-ctrlf)

Comment: Incompatible line delimiter with this one as well

Comment: `\r` shouldn't be necessary. As long as the text is loaded, Eclipse treats any line delimiter as a single `\n`.

Comment: If I do Find:  ^\s*\r?\n and replace with: nothing I get "string not found"

Comment: That just means Eclipse didn't find a line with such a delimiter. Have you checked out the related post?

Comment: Also tried converting to Unix before executing the actions in your (adjusted) post?

Comment: Yes I changed line delimiters to UNIX and retried all of the find and replaces with the same results.